# How to filter from undefined values?

Tags: angularjs

I get data from a Tomcat server. Data are JSON formated as:

```
[
    {name: "Smith",
    address: [
        {city: "LA"},
        {city: "NY"}
    ],
    firstName: "Rob"},
    {/* Idem */}
]
```

One of my controllers set these data into `$scope.people` which is bound on my views into a table with loops. But some of raws doesn't appears when the adress array is empty.

How can I replace each of my empty array with a `-` string? Is there a filter for this?

Comment: Can you also add the implementation in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use custom filter where you can implement any logic you want.

Something like:

**HTML**

```
  <tr data-ng-repeat="hotel in names |  myfilter:replaceWith">
```

**JS**

```
iApp.filter('myfilter', function() {

   var replaceWith = 'none';

   var replaceMe = function(value){
      if(value === undefined){
            return replaceWith;
          }
          return value;
   };

   return function( items, rw) {
    var filtered = [];
    replaceWith = rw;

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {

        item.name      = replaceMe(item.name);
        item.firstName = replaceMe(item.firstName);
        item.address   = replaceMe(item.address);

       filtered.push(item);
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yC0ntXMlXq0OhyFwv7ap?p=preview)**</kbd>

[image]

> Beware! The filtered list should have the same item structure like input list. Otherwise you can get *10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!*